# Сравнение чисел в машине Тьюринга

Tags: алгоритм, сравнение

Подскажите пожалуйста алгоритм сравнения чисел в бинарной системе в машине Тьюринга. При этом сами числа должны остаться на ленте. После сравнения чисел их нужно упорядочить по возрастанию, то есть сделать сортировку. Числа в бинарной системе вводятся через пробел. Алфавит: числа, буквы, знаки. Использую эмулятор Дикарева(в машине одна бесконечная лента)

Comment: Ответ на этот вопрос зависит от того, насколько сложно поддержка чисел у вас выстроена. Если это простые integer - то тупо сравнение двух integer. Если в машине реализована поддержка нескольких типов данных - то что бы не городить мульти-сравнение, думаю проще это реализовать через оператор/метод класса. Если результат нужно записать в стек - записывается 0 или 1. Вот собственно и всё.

Comment: @nick_n_a, это вопрос про специальный вид компьютера - [машину Тьюринга](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%A2%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0). Там нет типов и классов, только символы на ленте.

Comment: @gambil, какой нужен ответ? Равно? Не равно? Больше? Меньше? Определите формат записи чисел и разделителей на ленте.

Comment: Алгоритм очень сильно зависит от того, сколько лент в вашей машине, какой алфавит, какой максимальный размер целых. Добавьте описание машины в ваш вопрос. Ожидаемый результат тоже уточните - машина сравнивает равно/не равно или меньше/равно/больше?

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос, добавил все детали, обратите пожалуйста внимание

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос примеры ленты до работы и после.